# Plotting along a path in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

In D3.js, to draw a line I would define the line function, which would look something like this:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
           .x(function(d) { return x(d.distance); })
           .y(function(d) { return y(d.speed); });
```

This is the function I would call to render the speed recorded during a bike tour, for example. The `distance` axis is horizontal.

But, actually, the bike trail is not horizontal, and I have available the `elevation` variable inside the data object. How can I use that to plot the speed along the **actual** bike trail, showing the ups and downs, and the relative increases and decreases of speed?

In your experience, what is the best approach to plotting a variable along a path? The x-axis should be coincident with the defined path, and the y-axis always perpendicular to it.

I am thinking of using ["Point-Along-Path interpolation"](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868), together with some kind of derivative calculation to know what the perpendicular direction would be... and then find the x,y coordinates of the given point.

But maybe I am not using some terribly simple solution as the one used in *"Curved textPath"* (Mike bostock's block #2565344), that only uses the `hlink` property of the `text` element. Hope you can shed some light on this!

**EDIT:** I added [an example image](http://s4.postimg.org/mcyqicq5p/Bend_X_Axis.jpg) to further express what I meant by "plotting a variable along a path". Note that the path is used to set the shape of the x-axis.

Comment: Ok, so you have 3 variables and want to plot them all in a line? That's not going to work. You could plot the actual trail and color-code it according to speed for example.

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself incorrectly. Please see [the example image I prepared](http://s4.postimg.org/mcyqicq5p/Bend_X_Axis.jpg) and it will show more clearly what I meant by "plotting a variable along a path".

The variable plotted is the same. But the axis is now "bent" according to another relationship.

Comment: Ah, I see. That looks like it would be tricky to do with D3; I'm certainly not aware of any examples like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer involves using `getPointAtLength` and `getTotalLength` properties of paths.

The approach I followed was:

1. Find the point in the path @ a given distance.
2. Find the perpendicular unit vector @ that point.
3. Use the coordinates of the point and the perpendicular vector to find the coordinates of the point I wanted to plot.

Here's the [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/p-panichelli/pen/vEvaPw) that shows how I got it to work.

This is how a step plot looks when plotted along a curve: [LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGIOe.png)

*(not yet allowed to post images)*...